# How to initialize a std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream

I need to concatenate a string with integers. To do that I'm using `stringstream` in the following way:

```
int numPeople = 10;
stringstream ss;
ss << "Number of people is " << numPeople;
```

And that worked. But I was trying to do it in the way below:

```
int numPeople = 10;
stringstream ss << "Number of people is " << numPeople;
```

And I was getting the following error: "**expected initializer before '<<' token**"

Why was I getting this error? Why can't I assign the `stringstream` value at the same time I declare it?

Comment: That's just the way it is. The only thing you're allowed to do in a declaration is to construct the object you're declaring.

Comment: I guess this one liner alternative is still a clean option.

`stringstream ss; ss << "Number of people is " << numPeople;`

Comment: @Brian - Even if the OP used the word "declare" in his question, he clearly did not mean to limit to a declaration.
His one liner may contain more than a call to the constructor (e.g., `stringstream ss = "Number of people is "`).
His problem was using the value of `numPeople` in that one liner.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
stringstream ss << "Number of people is " << numPeople;
```

> Why can't I assign the `stringstream` value at the same time I declare it?

This is similar to hoping this would work...

```
int x + 3 + 9;
```

...but this doesn't parse as a variable definition, let alone a definition and assignment.

### The legal way to define and initialise an object

The only ways to define *and* initialise a variable with a non-default value are (in a grammar sense - this isn't code):

```
type identifier(...args...);
type identifier{...args...};
type identifier = ...expression...;
```

The last notation is equivalent to the first - i.e. `type identifier(arg)` where arg is passed the `...expression...`.

### Trying to use the legal notation for int and stringstream

For `int`, you can easily correct the code:

```
int x = 3 + 9;
```

...and it works because "3 + 9" can be evaluated independently *first* to give a sane value to store in `x`.  *The compiler's behaviour for operator `+` on `int`s does what we want*: it produces the `int` result we then want to store in `x`.  You can think of the above as:

```
        // evaluate the expression to assign first...
        ((int)3 + (int)9); // notate the implicit types
        (int)12;           // evaluate expression => value to assign
int x = (int)12;           // then think about doing the assignment
int x((int)12);            // construct a valid value
```

It works!  But if you try that for `stringstream`...

```
stringstream ss = "Number of people is " << numPeople;  // BROKEN
                  "Number of people is " << numPeople; // bitshift?!
```

...it won't work, because `"Number of people is " << numPeople` needs to be evaluated first but is illegal - you'll get an error like:

```
error C2296: '<<' : illegal, left operand has type 'const char [20]'
```

The problem is that the compiler's still trying to apply the bitwise shift operation, which only makes sense for numbers, because the overloads for `<<` that we want to use require that any "X << Y" code has the left-hand part "X" be - or be implicitly convertible to - an `ostream&`.  A string literal can't be converted.  At this point, the compiler is oblivious to the `stringstream` to which the result of the expression will be passed.

### A solution for stringstream

It's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem, because you need to combine the right-hand values you want in the `stringstream` to call the `stringstream`'s constructor, but for that you need... a `stringstream`.  You can actually pull that off with a temporary `stringstream`:

```
static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(std::ostringstream{} << "Number of people is " << numPeople)
```

The cast is unfortunately needed because the `operator<<` overloads handle `stringstream`s via references to their `ostream` base class, returning an `ostream&`, so you need to cast back to the `stringstream` type manually, so you can then invoke the `std::stringstream` move constructor...

The complete one-liner construction is then...

```
std::ostringstream ss(static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(std::ostringstream{} << "Number of people is " << numPeople));
...or...
auto&& ss = static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(std::ostringstream{} << "Number of people is " << numPeople);
```

...but that's too hideous to contemplate.

### Making the solution (arguably) less hideous with macros

Yes, you read that right.  Depending on your sensibilities, you may feel a macro helps or is worse...

```
#define OSS(VALUES) \
    static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(std::ostringstream{} << VALUES)

auto&& ss = OSS("Number of people is " << numPeople);
```

FWIW, you could also use the macro to create strings...

```
auto&& s = OSS("Number of people is " << numPeople).str();
```

...or create a dedicated macro...

```
#define STR(VALUES) \
    static_cast<std::ostringstream&&>(std::ostringstream{} << VALUES).str()
auto&& s = STR("Number of people is " << numPeople);
```

### An (arguably) better practice - separate construction and initialisation

Just create the `stringstream` - optionally providing a single `string` to the constructor - then use `operator<<` in a second statement:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Number of people is " << numPeople;
```

This is much easier to read, and there are no weird macros required.

### An alternative

C++11 introduced [`to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) overloads which are convenient if you have an integral value or two to concatentate with or into a `string`:

```
auto&& s = "Number of people is " + std::to_string(numPeople);
```

This may be inefficient though (check your compiler(s) optimisation abilities if you care): each `std::to_string()` is likely to dynamically allocate a buffer for an independent `std::string` instance, then the individual concatenations may involve extra copying of text, and the original dynamically-allocated buffers may need to be enlarged, then most of those temporary `std::string`s will take time to deallocate during destruction.

### Discussion

Ideally, `std::stringstream` would have a constructor accepting an arbitrary number of constructor arguments `(A, B, C...)` to be formatted into the `stringstream` as if by a subsequent `<< A << B << C...`.  There are already constructors with arguments (e.g. `(std::ios_base::openmode, const Allocator&)`), so we'd need a placeholder to distinguish such arguments from values we're trying to format into the stream, or a weirder workaround like requiring the values to be formatted into the stream be passed in as an initialiser list.

Still, it looks and feels very weird using strings with `,` instead of `<<`:

```
std::stringstream ss{"n:", std::setw(4), std::hex, '\n'};
```

And then if during code maintenance you find you need to move the streaming values to a point after construction, you'd need to change the separator.  Breaking it out into two lines to start with - construction then streaming - simplifies that maintenance.

### It was worse in C++03

C++03 lacked move constructors, so it was necessary to use the [`std::ostringstream::str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) member function on the temporary to get an extra deep-copy of the `std::string` with which to construct the named `stringsteam`...

```
stringstream ss(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << "Number of people is " << numPeople).str());
```

With this C++03 code, there's a likelihood of duplicate dynamic memory allocations (unless the strings are short enough to fit inside the string object, a commonly provided `std::string` technique called "Short String Optimisation" or SSO).  There's also a deep copy of textual content.  Construction-followed-by-streaming was a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

The stringbuf has to be initialized before values can be added to it.  stringstream is an object.

By doing:

```
std::stringstream ss;
```

You are essentially allowing the application to allocate space to handle the to-be added values.