# how to reuse istringstream in cplusplus

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to reuse istringstream variable. It is easy to initial istringstream variable using construction function. But when I try to re-assign it to a new value using `=` or `<<`, I got error. I am using c++11. It seems no compile error in vs 2015 using `=`. But gcc 4.8.2 (devtools-2 on Centos 6.4 x86_64) get error.

Codes like below:

```
std::string line;

int simmulationtimes; double InitialIDensity;

// deploy configuration file
std::ifstream config(configfile);
if (!config.is_open())
{
       return false;
}
std::getline(config, line);
std::istringstream sline(line);
std::string sInitialIDensity;
while(std::getline(sline, sInitialIDensity, '=')); 
InitialIDensity = std::stod(sInitialIDensity);

std::getline(config, line);
std::string ssimmulationtimes;
sline.str("");  sline.clear();
sline = std::istringstream(line);
while (std::getline(sline, ssimmulationtimes, '='));
simmulationtimes = std::stoi(ssimmulationtimes);
```

configuration file should be:

```
IDensity=0.5
times=5
```

Error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::istringstream {aka std::basic_istringstream<char>}’ and ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’)
  sline = std::istringstream(line);
```

Solutions (like [how-to-initialize-a-stdstringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924156/how-to-initialize-a-stdstringstream)) on stackoverflow about reusing stringstream not work for me. Any ideas about reusing istringstream? Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: It is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `str()` method to [set a new `std::string` into an existing `std::istringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/istringstream/str/).

Comment: It seems no compile error in vs 2015 using =. But gcc 4.8.2 (devtools-2 on Centos 6.4 x86_64) get error.